# Unreal Engine 4 - Add offset to character movement

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I just started (yesterday) using unreal engine and  I need to simulate a drunk character using BPs.

I'm using two camera shakes (one for standing still and one for walking) but I want to add some "displacement" on charater when he's walking.
Basically I want to define a random float to be added to X axis location in order to make character wobble smoothly.

It will be acceptable even if there's a way to make the character move along with the camera when it's shaking.

What I tried until now is using AddActorLocalOffset and a timeline to lerp between actor's location and actor's location+offset, but both are very choppy to me.

Maybe it's a noob question but as I told I'm very new to this and need it for a quick work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targetting physically correct model, you should use `AddForce` ([UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Pawn/Components/CharacterMovement/AddForce/index.html)). But this approach would require implementation of a "drunk animation" where your character will modify it's movement animation to "compensate" this force by stepping aside etc.

Another (much more simple) approach is by using `AddMovementInput`. This example can be seen here: [UE Aswers](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/336672/how-do-i-make-moving-in-a-straight-line-difficult.html). In this case, you are basically simulate player's input by adding small amount of side force here and there.